# Read Only For Some Documents But Not Others

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, workgroup

I have a client who have a Windows 2003 Server acting as a file share and DHCP server. The server is not setup as a domain, it just uses a workgroup called COMPANY.

There are a few file shares on the server. Some of them work fine, users are able to open, modify and delete documents. On some shares however, every document opens in read-only mode. When I copy the file to the local desktop, then try to copy it back, it says I do not have permission.

On the folders I have done every permission option I can find, to give domain users, users, everyone, created a user on the server called the user account on the PC - all with full control of the folder and documents in them.

Please help, I have run out of ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses two levels of authentication here: share level and file level. Have you given read and write permissions on the share? It sounds like you've done it on the file level.